# How can i add 1 to this score

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i'm working on a tic tac toe game ,
i want that when i finish the game i mean X or O Win ( a block of X or O ) i want that the round number change from 1 to 2 and i clear all the field ( i used button as a field and the button text as the X or O )
this is a part of code: the B1 , B2 , B3 vars , when they have an 1 as a value mean that an X is done on that field

```
if (B1 == 1 && B2 == 1 && B3 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
            Form1 Form = new Form1();
            Form.Dispose();
        }
```

and on the Form.Load i wrote this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        round++;
        label3.Text = "Round: " + round.ToString();
    }
```

it doesn't work any solu ?

and i defined the var here

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }
    byte player = 1;
    byte B1 = 0;
    byte B2 = 0;
    byte B3;
    byte B4;
    byte B5;
    byte B6;
    byte B7;
    byte B8;
    byte B9;
    byte round;
    byte Player1, Player2;
```

For The Whole code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }
    byte player = 1;
    byte B1 = 0;
    byte B2 = 0;
    byte B3;
    byte B4;
    byte B5;
    byte B6;
    byte B7;
    byte B8;
    byte B9;
    byte round;
    byte Player1, Player2;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B1 == 0)
            {
                button1.Text = "X";
                B1 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B1 == 0)
            {
                button1.Text = "O";
                B1 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B2 == 0)
            {
                button2.Text = "X";
                B2 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B2 == 0)
            {
                button2.Text = "O";
                B2 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B3 == 0)
            {
                button3.Text = "X";
                B3 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B3 == 0)
            {
                button3.Text = "O";
                B3 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B5 == 0)
            {
                button5.Text = "X";
                B5 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B5 == 0)
            {
                button5.Text = "O";
                B5 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B4 == 0)
            {
                button4.Text = "X";
                B4 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B4 == 0)
            {
                button4.Text = "O";
                B4 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B9 == 0)
            {
                button9.Text = "X";
                B9 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B9 == 0)
            {
                button9.Text = "O";
                B9 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B7 == 0)
            {
                button7.Text = "X";
                B7 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B7 == 0)
            {
                button7.Text = "O";
                B7 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B8 == 0)
            {
                button8.Text = "X";
                B8 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B8 == 0)
            {
                button8.Text = "O";
                B8 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            if (B6 == 0)
            {
                button6.Text = "X";
                B6 = 1;
                player = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (player == 2)
        {
            if (B6 == 0)
            {
                button6.Text = "O";
                B6 = 2;
                player = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (B1 == 1 && B2 == 1 && B3 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B4 == 1 && B5 == 1 && B6 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B7 == 1 && B8 == 1 && B9 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B1 == 1 && B4 == 1 && B7 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B2 == 1 && B5 == 1 && B8 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B3 == 1 && B6 == 1 && B9 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B1 == 1 && B5 == 1 && B9 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }
        if (B3 == 1 && B5 == 1 && B7 == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X Win");
        }

    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        round++;
        label3.Text = "Round: " + round.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Where did you define `round`?

Comment: I think that we need a more complete overview. If round is not a global variable, it will not work.

Comment: Would you declare 64 methods like `private void buttonNNN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` if it would be a chess game?

Comment: I'd like to see your code for [go (19x19)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game))

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the variable `round` outside of your form. As you destroy the form each time, the current round number gets lost as well.

You need to store it wherever you open your form from. I also suggest increasing the round number before you open the form and passing the increased value to the form for display. This way you will keep all the logic about rounds in one place.

Comment: Where do you open your `Form1` from?